# reindex with DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, reindex

I would like to use

```
In[9]: datums_index
Out[9]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2021-08-27', '2021-07-28', '2021-06-28', '2021-05-27',
               '2021-04-27', '2021-03-26', '2021-02-24', '2021-01-25',
               '2020-12-24', '2020-11-24',
               ...
               '2012-06-19', '2012-05-18', '2012-04-18', '2012-03-19',
               '2012-02-16', '2012-01-17', '2011-12-16', '2011-11-16',
               '2011-10-17', '2011-09-15'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Datum', length=119, freq=None)
```

To reindex the Series

```
In[10]: optimalisatie
Out[10]: 
0    Datum    {'x': [-0.06623109894765111, 0.526934087237806...
1    Datum    {'x': [-0.06623109894765111, 0.526934087237806...
2    Datum    {'x': [-0.017442659275313556, 0.52397157909587...
3    Datum    {'x': [-0.017442659275313556, 0.52397157909587...
4    Datum    {'x': [-0.046872910256038305, 0.36958204592514...
                       
114  Datum    {'x': [-0.017442659275313556, 0.52397157909587...
115  Datum    {'x': [-0.017442659275313556, 0.52397157909587...
116  Datum    {'x': [-0.007317742455425033, 0.81146104977826...
117  Datum    {'x': [0.019622151571529925, 0.113712588771878...
118  Datum    {'x': [-0.007748994581445918, 0.55552128362233...
Length: 119, dtype: object
```

Which has the following multidindex:

```
In[11]: optimalisatie.index
Out[11]: 
MultiIndex([(  0, 'Datum'),
            (  1, 'Datum'),
            (  2, 'Datum'),
            (  3, 'Datum'),
            (  4, 'Datum'),
            (  5, 'Datum'),
            (  6, 'Datum'),
            (  7, 'Datum'),
            (  8, 'Datum'),
            (  9, 'Datum'),
            ...
            (109, 'Datum'),
            (110, 'Datum'),
            (111, 'Datum'),
            (112, 'Datum'),
            (113, 'Datum'),
            (114, 'Datum'),
            (115, 'Datum'),
            (116, 'Datum'),
            (117, 'Datum'),
            (118, 'Datum')],
           length=119)
```

I do, however, get the following error:

```
In[12]: optimalisatie.reindex(datums_index)
TypeError: Argument 'tuples' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got DatetimeArray)
```

Eventhough the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html says

```
New labels / index to conform to, should be specified using keywords. Preferably an Index object to avoid duplicating data.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need to give more details, such as an example of the data

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? As far as I understand I added all data